# Galaxy S2 Skyrocket acting very strange

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

My Android GS2 Skyrocket problems began with battery error "Charging stopped due to battery temperature" so I bought a new OEM battery which I hoped would solve but it hasn't.

Phone is not rooted and I'm not sure what processing is being used. Every time I've checked for an update...never had to since I received my phone.

The phone powers up with new battery but now I can't get past the unlock pattern. It doesn't recognize my gmail login or password. I bought an app to help with the unlock pattern but its not working as it should due to phone error somewhere. It won't even let calls ring through, goes straight to voicemail.

I noticed the when the phone restarts, the date and time are not current anymore. It resets to January 1st, 6 pm. I have notice a Google Play error now when it starts back up which may be reason why the Unlock Pattern app I just bought isn't working properly.

Not quite a brick, I don't want to do a factory reset because I will lose everything new since last backup.

Any ideas or solutions, before I send off for repair or buy a new phone..I really don't want to..

Thanks

Comment: Why is sending it for a repair or replacing it okay but a reset isn't?

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously some serious issues with your configuration and possibly (the battery issue) the device. If you cannot access the device with the pattern or your Gmail login, you will need to factory reset it. With all the other issues you are having, it is probably your best option anyway. Plus if you send it for repair, that will be the first thing that gets done to it anyway.